# Scala convert Map[A, Seq[Future[Option[B]]]] to Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]]?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've been stuck and was wondering how I can convert `Map[A, Seq[Future[Option[B]]]]` to `Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]]`?

Comment: How did you end up with that type? Maybe it would be easier to avoid getting in there. Give us some functions and their types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be something like:

```
val yourMap: Map[A, Seq[Future[Option[B]]]] = ...

val flattenedValues: Map[A, Future[Seq[B]]] = yourMap.mapValues { seqFuture =>
  Future.sequence(seqFuture).map(seqOpt => seqOpt.flatten)
}

val seqOfFutures: Seq[Future[(A, Seq[B])]] = flattenedValues.toSeq.map {
  case (a, futureSeqB) =>
    future.map(optionB => a -> optionB)
}

val futureOfSeq: Future[Seq[(A, Seq[B])]] = Future.sequence(seqOfFutures)

val result: Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]] = futureOfSeq.map { seq =>
  seq.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).flatten)
}
```

What you had before edition of your question (`Map[A, Future[Option[B]]`) would be handled simpler way with cats if you had 2 things defined

```
// as far as I can tell defined only in Alleycats
implicit def traverseMap[A]: cats.Traverse[Map[A, *]] = ...
// as far as I can tell defined in Cats
implicit def applicativeFuture: cats.Applicative[Future] = ...
```

then you could do it simply with:

```
// assuming traverse syntax imported
val futureMap: Future[Map[A, Option[B]] = yourMap.sequence
```

the data in your current form, however, forces us to do it in a hard way.

Comment: You can just do `result = futureOfSeq.map(_.toMap)` rather than regrouping, and you can combine the first two steps into a single `.toSeq.map`. There is also a typo where `future.map` should be `futureSeqB.map`. Also `.map(...).flatten` is `.flatMap(...)`. Finally, beware that `mapValues` is lazy so that last operation is repeated every time a value is read from `Map`

Answer (score 0):

This version avoid re-grouping the data by converting the `Map` to `List` and then back again.

```
val in: Map[A, Seq[Future[Option[B]]]] = ???

val out: Future[Map[A, Seq[B]]] =
  Future.sequence(
    in.toList.map {
      case (k, v) => Future.sequence(v).map(k -> _.flatten)
    }
  ).map(_.toMap)
```

The inner `map` uses `Future.sequence` to convert each entry from `A -> Seq[Future[Option[B]]]` to `Future[A -> Seq[B]]`.

The outer `Future.sequence` converts the `List[Future[A -> Seq[B]]]` to `Future[List[A -> Seq[B]]]`.

The outer `map` converts this `List` back to a `Map`.

This compiles so the types are right, but I have not tested it on any real data